# Where can I find documentation for Ext.nd framework?

Tags: extjs, lotus-notes

There's a good web-framework for Notes/Domino, called [Ext.nd](http://www.openntf.org/Projects/pmt.nsf/ProjectLookup/Ext.nd)

In download package there's html documentation present, but some important links are broken.

Links on to official page also are broken: http://www.sencha.com/learn/general-questions/

Where can I find a decent documentation/tutorials for this framework?

Comment: You should probably send a mail/comment to one of the owners on OpenNTF (the link you posted).

Comment: I've posted a question on to official sencha/ext.js forum, but no-one responded yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs are now online as well as the source.

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?252711-Extnd-docs-are-now-online